# Laravel 5.2: How to change users' role？

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 and `Zizaco/entrust` 5.2,
How to change users' role？
For example:
**users**

```
id      name         email                   password 
1       Jim          Jim@example.com         ******
```

**roles**

```
id       name 
1        vip
2        ordinary
```

**role_user**

```
user_id      role_id
1                1
```

Jim's role  is vip ,and the vip role will expire in 30 days,how to change vip to  ordinary when expired?

Comment: You need to show what you've tried to solve this, but as a starting point take a look at commands (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan) and task scheduling (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling). You're likely going to need some sort of daily (or more frequent) cron job that watches for expiration and modifies the role accordingly.

Comment: reading the documentation probably helps! (y)

Answer (score 0):

Have an expiry date on the role_user table, and run your query such that only records with an expiry date in the future are selected. (You may want to also include NULL expiry dates to allow for those that don't expire).